# @Column (Cassandra) annotation ignored with Spring Boot 2.5.0 (works with 2.4.6)

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, cassandra

While trying to update a project using `spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra` from Spring Boot `2.4.6` to `2.5.0`, I run into a problem of my `@Column` annotations being ignored.

Using the following annotation

```kotlin
    @Column("blabla")
    val buz: Long
```

results in this error:

```
Query; CQL [INSERT INTO bar (baz,buz) VALUES (?,?)]; Undefined column name buz; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.InvalidQueryException: Undefined column name buz
```

So the query uses `buz` instead of `blabla` as intended. With Spring Boot `2.4.6` instead of `2.5.0` it works fine. Has something changed, so that I need to adjust my code, or is this a bug?

The problem seems to come from `spring-data-cassandra`, which updates with Spring Boot.

- When using Spring Boot `2.4.6` and `implementation(group = "org.springframework.data", name = "spring-data-cassandra", version = "3.1.9")` things are fine.
- When using Spring Boot `2.4.6` and `implementation(group = "org.springframework.data", name = "spring-data-cassandra", version = "3.2.0")` things fail.

It looks like the whole `@Column` annotation is ignored because `forceQuote = true` is also not used when I add it.

The following minimal example can be used (`docker build .`) to reproduce the error:

### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
WORKDIR /home/test
ADD . /home/test
RUN ./gradlew test
```

### `build.gradle.kts`

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

val kotlinVersion = "1.5.10"
val springBootVersion = "2.4.6"

plugins {
    val pluginKotlinVersion = "1.5.10"
    val pluginSpringBootVersion = "2.5.0"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version pluginSpringBootVersion
    kotlin("jvm") version pluginKotlinVersion
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version pluginKotlinVersion
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version pluginKotlinVersion
}

group = "com.acme"
version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation(
        group = "org.springframework.boot",
        name = "spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra",
        version = springBootVersion
    )

    // 3.1.9 -> fine
    // 3.2.0 -> broken
    // 3.2.1 -> broken
    implementation(group = "org.springframework.data", name = "spring-data-cassandra", version = "3.2.0")

    implementation(group = "org.springframework.boot", name = "spring-boot-starter-web", version = springBootVersion)

    implementation(group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name = "kotlin-reflect", version = kotlinVersion)

    implementation(
        group = "org.cassandraunit",
        name = "cassandra-unit-spring",
        version = "4.3.1.0"
    ) {
        exclude(group = "org.hibernate")
        testImplementation(group = "com.google.guava", name = "guava") {
            version {
                // https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/issues/248
                // https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15245
                strictly("18.0")
            }
        }
    }

    testImplementation(
        group = "org.springframework.boot",
        name = "spring-boot-starter-test",
        version = springBootVersion
    )

}

tasks {
    withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
            jvmTarget = "11"
        }
    }

    withType<Test> {
        testLogging.exceptionFormat = org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat.FULL
    }
}
```

### `settings.gradle.kts`

```
rootProject.name = "acmetest"
```

### `src/main/kotlin/com/acme/Application.kt`

```
package com.acme

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Column
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKey
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}

@Table("bar")
class Bar(

    @PrimaryKey("baz")
    val baz: Long,

    @Column("blabla")
    val buz: Long
)

@Repository
interface BarRepository : CassandraRepository<Bar, Long>
```

### `src/main/resources/application.yml`

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      contact-points: localhost
      port: 9142
      keyspace_name: foo
      local-datacenter: datacenter1
```

### `src/test/kotlin/com/acme/integration/TestFullStack.kt`

```
package com.acme.integration


import com.acme.Bar
import com.acme.BarRepository
import org.cassandraunit.spring.CassandraDataSet
import org.cassandraunit.spring.CassandraUnitDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener
import org.cassandraunit.spring.EmbeddedCassandra
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles
import org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListeners
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner

@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestExecutionListeners(
    listeners = [CassandraUnitDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener::class],
    mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS
)
@CassandraDataSet(value = ["cql/foo.cql"], keyspace = "foo")
@EmbeddedCassandra
class TestFullStack {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var barRepository: BarRepository

    @Test
    fun `test init`() {
        barRepository.save(Bar(1, 2))
    }
}
```

### `src/test/resources/cql/foo.cql`

```
DROP KEYSPACE IF EXISTS foo;

CREATE KEYSPACE foo WITH REPLICATION = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1};

CREATE TABLE foo.bar
(
    baz     bigint,
    blabla  bigint,
    PRIMARY KEY (baz)
);
```

Comment: You are using `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.4.31` with 1.5.0 version of Kotlin plugin. Maybe this breaks annotation processing magic (which relies on reflection)?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь Thanks for the idea, but no, I was using `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.5.0` (coming from `implementation(group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name = "kotlin-reflect", version = kotlinVersion)` with `val kotlinVersion = "1.5.0"`). `val pluginKotlinVersion = "1.4.31"` is just the version used for the Gradle plugins. I've just updated both to `1.5.10` (and adjusted the code in my question accordingly), but it makes no difference in the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, the issue seems to be with having the members of `Bar` already declared in the constructor. I.e., replacing this

```kotlin
@Table("bar")
class Bar(

    @PrimaryKey("baz")
    val baz: Long,

    @Column("blabla")
    val buz: Long
)
```

with that

```kotlin
@Table("bar")
class Bar(baz: Long, buz: Long) {

    @PrimaryKey("baz")
    val baz: Long = baz

    @Column("blabla")
    val buz: Long = buz
}
```

makes it work again.

With version `3.1.9` of `org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra` both are working fine, but the first one breaks when updating to `3.2.0`. We've opened an issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/issues/1136

---

Edit 2022-02-01: The following works too:

```kotlin
@Table("bar")
class Bar(

    @PrimaryKey("baz")
    val baz: Long,

    @field:Column("blabla")
    val buz: Long
)
```